# Html Image size when added via Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, html, outlook, automation

Using MS outlook 2010, c# in Visual Studio 2012, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook version 14.

I'm trying to use outlook automation to open a new email, pre-populated with some html.

Here's the code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

...

            // bring up outlook
            Application oApp = new Application();
            Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            oMailItem.To = "any@any.com";    

            string body = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("welcome.html");

            oMailItem.HTMLBody = body;
            oMailItem.Subject = "Welcome";

            oMailItem.Display(false);
```

Where welcome.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body lang="EN-AU">        
              <p>hello world</p>   <!-- XXX : repeat as necessary -->
            <p>   
            <img src="http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg" alt="logo" />
            </p>    

</body>
</html>
```

Note: any logo (which is not too small) can be used - the one I have used is just an example.

The code works ok, but there is a problem with the logo size. 
The problem can occur when the html line marked at XXX is repeated many times, (say 50).

There are two cases:

a) in outlook, before you send the email, scroll down to view the complete document. I noticed that outlook seems to resize the image. When the email is sent, the receiver sees the image in normal size:

[image: Case A]

b) in outlook, before you send the email, DO NOT scroll down to view the complete document. When the email is received, the image is small. (32 pixels by 32 pixels):

[image: Case B]

The email resulting from case a) is the desired outcome. But it would be better if the user didn't have to scroll down to preview the whole thing before sending.

Any workarounds ? Using html width and height attributes on img to explicitly set the dimensions seems to work, but this is not desirable because in real life, the image is dynamically selected (so that the size can't be hardcoded). If there was some way (via automation) to simulate previewing the whole email before sending, this might work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moe,

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: thanks, useful info on the limitations. It didn't really help though with trying to get a workaround in place.